Seeking Help: I want to integrate React based front screen with Magento admin panel and functions
Hello Sir here is my Question:
I'm new to Magento and currently exploring the code base. After installing Magento 2.4.7, I'm interested in making changes to the B2B Admin Panel UI directly from the project directory. Specifically, I'd like to modify elements such as changing the name "Dashboard" to "Dash."
My ultimate goal is to integrate a React-based frontend with the Magento admin panel and its functions. I want to create a seamless experience where all products are displayed in the existing eCommerce format, allowing users to browse and make purchases. Since the existing eCommerce site is built with React, I aim to integrate this frontend with Magento's admin panel features.
Could someone provide guidance on how I can achieve this? Any insights or resources to kick-start this integration process would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
Chy

If you want to developed fronted into React Based, then you need to go with following themes.

Hyva : https://www.hyva.io/

Scandi PWA : https://scandipwa.com/

Breeze : https://breezefront.com/


